# SQL ORACLE help on query(ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis)

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to get the names of people that never own the most popular vehicle in each type of car (yearly for all cars ,suv,sedan..etc). The most popular vehicle of a type in a given year is the maker and model with more vehicles registered than any others in its type.

these are the tables that i created 
auto_sale( transaction_id,seller_id(sin), buyer_id(sin), vehicle_id(serial_no), s_date(yyyymmdd), price )
people( sin, name)
vehicle( serial_no, maker, model, year, color, type_id )

This is the query that i came up with that dosen't work, it's kept on saying too many values, i tried having aliases for the sub query in vehicle.maker/model= (...) to clarify the joined table, but it's kept on saying missing right parentheses,so please show me some shine on this query.

```
select people.name
from auto_sale,people
where name not in(select people.name from people,auto_sale,vehicle where buyer_id = people.sin and
                  auto_sale.vehicle_id=vehicle.serial_no and
                  vehicle.maker = (select vehicle.maker
                                from (auto_sale
                                     join
                                     vehicle
                                     on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no)v1
                                group by extract(year from to_date(v1.s_date,'yyyymmdd'), maker
                                having count(*) >= all(select count(*)
                                                       from (auto_sale
                                                       join
                                                       vehicle
                                                       on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no)v2
                                                       where extract(year from to_date(v1.s_date,'yyyymmdd')=
                                                       extract(year from to_date(v2.s_date,'yyyymmdd')
                                                       group by extract(year from to_date(v2.s_date,'yyyymmdd'),ma\
ker,type_id) ) and
                  vehicle.model = (select vehicle.model
                                from (auto_sale
                                     join
                                     vehicle
                                     on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no)v3
                                group by extract(year from todate(v3.s_date,'yyyymmdd'), model
                                having count(*) >= all(select count(*)
                                                       from (auto_sale
                                                       join
                                                       vehicle
                                                       on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no)v4
                                                       where extract(year from to_date(v3.s_date,'yyyymmdd')=
                                                       extract(year from to_date(v4.s_date,'yyyymmdd')
                                                       group by extract(year from to_date(s_date,'yyyymmdd'),v4mod\
el,v4.type_id))
                   group by people.name);
```

Comment: What is the error message, exactly, that you are getting?

Comment: ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: There is no `year()` function in Oracle

Comment: alright i edited to extract(year from to_date(s_date,'yyyymmdd'),thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At first I was writing all the modification I was doing to fix your syntax problem, but then when I realized it was the longest answer I've ever written and that no part of it was really instructive, I decided to just copy here the fixed query.

```
select people.name
from auto_sale,people
where name not in(select people.name 
                    from people,
                         auto_sale,
                         vehicle 
                    where buyer_id = people.sin 
                      and auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no
                      and vehicle.maker = (select vehicle.maker
                                            from auto_sale
                                            join vehicle on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no v1
                                            group by extract(year from to_date(v1.s_date,'yyyymmdd')), maker
                                            having count(*) >= all(select count(*)
                                                                        from auto_sale
                                                                        join vehicle on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no v2
                                                                        where extract(year from to_date(v1.s_date,'yyyymmdd')) = extract(year from to_date(v2.s_date,'yyyymmdd'))
                                                                        group by extract(year from to_date(v2.s_date,'yyyymmdd'),maker,type_id))) 
                      and vehicle.model = (select vehicle.model
                                            from auto_sale
                                            join vehicle on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no v3
                                            group by extract(year from todate(v3.s_date,'yyyymmdd')), model
                                            having count(*) >= all(select count(*)
                                                                    from auto_sale
                                                                    join vehicle on auto_sale.vehicle_id = vehicle.serial_no) v4
                                            where extract(year from to_date(v3.s_date,'yyyymmdd'))= extract(year from to_date(v4.s_date,'yyyymmdd'))
                                            group by extract(year from to_date(s_date,'yyyymmdd')),v4.model,v4.type_id))
group by people.name;
```

I have no idea how you were able to end up with so many syntax problems. Here some tip to avoid syntax problems :

- Write code in an editor that warn you when your syntax is strange
- Make sure to indent your code correctly
- Use the same editor as everyone in your team so that different people working on the same code won't break the syntax
- Some editors (example toad) allow to define a format template. When you are done writing the query, you can simply click format to have a readable syntax which will save you a lot of time debugging.

Note that I did not check if the query logic is good, just made sure to fix all syntax problem as it is your initial problem. I assume here that the rest is good.

Comment: i have soo many syntax problems because i just started learning haha, i usually just type it in emacs and batch run it in sqlplus, but now i downloaded the sql developer, hope it will help me more on the syntax problems.

Comment: thanks for your advice, i changed few of my codings already ,now it's working.

Comment: oh, and just for indentation,i don't know why when i copy on to here, it changes it

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns you are returning from the subquery should match the columns they are being compared to.

```
...  and 
      vehicle.maker = (select year(auto_sale.s_date), vehicle.maker
                        from 
...
```

Also,

```
... and
      vehicle.model = (select year(auto_sale.s_date), vehicle.model
                            from
...
```

It should instead be something like

```
... vehicle.maker = (select  vehicle.maker from ...
```

Something to keep in mind that the subquery should only return 1 row when using with '='.

Edit: On a second take, there are a lot of things that don't look right with this sql.

```
where year(s_date)=year(s_date)
```

Year seems to be a column in your table, so does s_date. Don't know what you are accomplishing with year(s_date). Even if it were valid syntax(which it isn't), both sides of the equation are the same, meaning the WHERE clause isn't needed there. You probably want to alias the tables at each level and use the conditions accordingly.

People and auto_sale are cross-joined in the top level query. Not sure if that is correct.

Comment: but now it's saying 
ERROR at line 6:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis